# wordpress - allow user to edit admin created page only

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for some advice on setting up wordpress to allow the following:

- admin creates 1->N pages, one for each user.
- a user is able to update their page only
- a user can log in to update their own profile only
- a user can not make any other changes
- the whole site (and all users pages) are viewable by anyone

I'm not sure if the above is possible out of the box, or with some plugins, but any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the user description for the editable content and then the user pages would be their public profiles, e.g. http://example.com/?author=123

You could use the author.php file to modify the appearance of that page. you can also set permalinks to true to make the links nice.